# Как заставить форму загрузки принимать только файлы PDF

Tags: javascript

У меня есть форма загрузки файла,мне нужно чтобы он принимал только PDF формат файла,а не фотки или другие формы файла

Comment: Вы можете проверить расширение или MIME-тип, но не формат. Если дюже умный юзер поменяет расширение - загрузит. Так что проверяйте внутренний формат на сервере после загрузки.

Comment: @Akina, не уверен, но можно попробовать открыть файл в скрытом блоке. Проверить - если открывается -то формат - норм

Comment: @Дмытрык *можно попробовать открыть файл в скрытом блоке.* Это - отдать проверку на откуп клиенту... а если у него запрещены просмотры PDF в браузере, или открытие файлов из браузера, или не установлен дефолтный PDF-вьювер? а если у него вьювер может открывать и картинки, и PDF, определяя тип по внутреннему формату, или вообще заглушка? Мало того что ненадёжно защищает от плохишей - так ведь можно нагадить порядочному юзеру, а это совсем ни в какие ворота.

Comment: @Akina, есть логика в Ваших словах).

Answer (score 0):

Используйте атрибут [accept](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/accept):

`<input type="file" name="upload" accept="application/pdf" />`